# How to force close Access application when user lost connection to back-end

Tags: ms-access, vba

The Question:
Is there some way to force close access so it doesn't need access to the back-end server in order to exit?

The Situation:
I have an Access 2016 DB. The back-end is on a networked share drive which is only accessible when connected to the lan or on VPN. On load there is a ping test to the server, if found it copies the tables to local tables, if not, it just tells the user can't connect and continues on using the old data. The users travel a lot and can't always be on the VPN so the idea is that the data they have isn't more than a few days old. BTW, did I mention the users are only consumers of information and not contributors so I don't care that they can't write to the back-end. The tables contain a few 100k records, the application just puts it in nice easy to search and cross-reference reports.

The Problem:
While this loads and runs really nicely regardless of them being connected to the lan or not, it will NOT close if they don't have a connection to the server. It doesn't produce an error which I could easily handle, it just hangs. Task Manager won't even close it.

Attempted Solutions:
I tried to unlink the tables and just use a temporary connection to the backend to load the tables when I need them at the beginning, however this meant the user was prompted by the Microsoft Trust Center about 8 times every single time they loaded this unless I have each of them actually open the back-end DB themselves, give them the password to do that, and none of that is practical.

Comment: Save the Import Steps to copy the tables from the Back End to their database. Have them Run the Saved Import when they connect to the VPN so the tables are copied. This way you never link them and it should not ask for Trust Center stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn't play well with remote BE..if you want to be on the Remote Side with Access you have 2 options :

- Connect via RDS..the user connects to the server via Remote Desktop ..everything is "local" ..so now issues on lost connections ...as long the RDP connection hold everything is smooth and more importantly you don't have BE disconnects that cause corruption or loosing data (hint : Using the RemoteApp technology it will seem to the end user like he/she is working locally...i am using it and its great)
- Switch BE...as i said , is not wise to use Access BE via remote connection..in order to do that switching to MsSQL/MySQL/PostGre ...etc will give you the true remote connection capability

Comment: I fought to put this in a SQL database but couldn't get it authorized. If I had a SQL database I had access to, I wouldn't be using Access at all.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with all the settings for a few days, I finally figured out what my problem was.
In an effort to test different settings to see if I could reduce file size at one point I turned on "clear cache on exit" in the Current Database settings. Turning this off fixed the problem. I had forgotten that was on, so it turned out to not be a programming issue after all.